# Why wont Pokemon Go let me sign into another google account

Tags: pokemon-go

I just recently got a new phone and wanted to sign into my Pokemon Go account from my old phone with my Google account, but all it does when I press sign up with google is makes me a new account.
Help?

Answer (score 0):

When you press to sign up with google it select the account you are using in your phone, or a list of the google accounts you have in order to select one. Try going to  Settings>Accounts and add the other phone account or make sure it is there.